# Learning from clicks on Ads

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, algorithms

I need to build an algorithm that predicts the number of clicks a facebook ad would get in the next 7 days.

Based on the given requirements, I prepared a dataset consisting of the following information for each ad:

1. **Landing page**: The URL that a user is redirected to upon
   clicking the ad.
2. **Bid term (“keywords”)**: The query for which this ad should
   be displayed
3. **Title**: The ad title, shown to the user.
4. **Body**: The text description of the ad.
5. **Display URL**: The URL shown to the user at the bottom of
   the ad.
6. **Clicks**: The number of times the ad has been clicked
7. **Views**: The number of times the ad has been seen

Should I go about implementing this using logistic regression considering the features that I already have or you would recommend any other model?

Comment: This strikes me as more of a question for marketing subject matter experts ("what would be some more useful information"), & as too broad ("how do I go about implementing this prediction model"), to be on topic here. If you have a narrow, concrete machine learning question, please edit to clarify. Otherwise, this is likely to be closed.

Comment: The research drives the question, but the statisticians drive the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** Should I go about implementing this using logistic regression considering the features that I already have or you would recommend any other model?

**Answer:** Maybe (no one knows as data is not enough). I assume that your goal is minimizing prediction error.

**Details on how to think about optimal solution:**

Say that your observations (learning set) are samples $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n$. So you have $n$ many samples in your learning set. For any $1 \le i \le n$, a sample $\mathbf{x}_i$ is represented as a 7 dimensional vector. So $\mathbf{x}_i[1]$ is the 1st component and represents the landing page URL, $\mathbf{x}_2[2]$ is the 2nd component and represents the bid term, and so on with the other features that you have found.

Your goal is essentially this:

- Find a function $m$ that transfers your 7-dimensional samples to some space (possibly the same space as the original 7 dimensional space, but maybe different).
- Analyse the transferred learning samples from the new space (after transferring them by $m$) in order to find a joint probability density function $f_{X,Y}$ of two random variables: $X$ which takes values in your samples set after transformation into the funny space by function $m$, and $Y$ which is takes values in the set of natural numbers which represents total clicks. If the function $m$ maps to a discrete space then replace this joint PDF by a joint PMF instead.

Obviously your learning set is finite, while the PDF or PMF are infinite. So you may find many accurate function $m$ and PDF/PMF on your learning set, but they could be inaccurate on the testing set.

Here you need to plug in your domain knowledge to cancel out the many possible $m$ and PDFs/PMFs that you know for sure to be unfit for the testing set. The more you apply correct domain knowledge to eliminate the unfit $m$ and PDF/PMF, the easier it is for you to find better models.

It's an open problem. You need to visualize your data, see if there are any patterns, study the economics behind (as gung suggested), and use this to build your domain knowledge to help you in your quest of finding the ultimate ads clicks predictions model given those 7 features.

Of course, you also have the choice of changing your features, but I am assuming that you have no choice in changing the features now.